# Canonically, who was the third rebel survivor of the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, the-rebel-alliance

According to my officially licenced *Star Wars* calendar, of the thirty X-wing and Y-wing pilots that participated in the Battle of Yavin, three returned.

[image: x]

We know that Luke and Wedge were two of the survivors, but who (if the calendar is actually accurate) was the third?

---

Note that it couldn't be referring to Han Solo, as he wasn't one of the original 30 pilots. Additionally, if it counted Han, it would have to count Chewbacca as well.

Wookieepedia tells me that in the Legends continuity, more than three pilots survived, so please limit your answers to the new canon.

Comment: Wookiepedia only mentions 2 surviving participants, Keyan Farlander (only surviving Y-Wing pilot) and Hamo Blastwell (presumed dead, but later resurfaced as an undercover agent). Given that you could argue that Hamo survived but never returned, I would assume that Keyan is still intended to be the third *returnee*, if not yet actually named in Canon.

Comment: Maybe they didn't count Chewie because he was merely a co-pilot?

Comment: I think Chewie would take exception to that theory, @Essen :)